# Extracting certain data from JSON without creating classes

Tags: c#, json.net

I need help in extracting certain data from my JSON in C#.  I am using Newtonsoft.Json.

I have a JSON string where I need only the value of `Id` (51927118485) and `Timestamp` (2020-05-20T09:11:08.937).  And under `Links` I need the value of `Next` (/google.com).

I don't want to create objects for all the elements in the JSON string.  I think I can use a `JObject` but I don't know how to proceed.

This is my sample code so far:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace api_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                string step2_resu = "{
  "Data": [
    {
      "Type": "MonitorCheck",
      "Id": 51927118485,
      "Attributes": {
        "MonitorGuid": "3c966ab3-af65-401a-a9e1-5c5e8e9300b5",
        "Timestamp": "2020-05-20T09:11:08.937",
        "ErrorCode": 0,
        "TotalTime": 4358,
        "ResolveTime": 0,
        "ConnectionTime": 0,
        "DownloadTime": 4358,
        "ErrorLevel": "NoError",
        "ErrorDescription": "OK",
        "ErrorMessage": "",
        "StagingMode": false,
        "ServerId": 860
      },
      "Relationships": [
        {
          "Id": 860,
          "Type": "CheckpointServer",
          "Links": {
            "Self": "/Checkpoint/Server/860"
          }
        },
        {
          "Id": 51927118485,
          "Type": "TransactionCheck",
          "Links": {
            "Self": "/MonitorCheck/51927118485/Transaction"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Type": "MonitorCheck",
      "Id": 51926636515,
      "Attributes": {
        "MonitorGuid": "3c966ab3-af65-401a-a9e1-5c5e8e9300b5",
        "Timestamp": "2020-05-20T08:56:10.997",
        "ErrorCode": 0,
        "TotalTime": 5098,
        "ResolveTime": 0,
        "ConnectionTime": 0,
        "DownloadTime": 5098,
        "ErrorLevel": "NoError",
        "ErrorDescription": "OK",
        "ErrorMessage": "",
        "StagingMode": false,
        "ServerId": 1020
      },
      "Relationships": [
        {
          "Id": 1020,
          "Type": "CheckpointServer",
          "Links": {
            "Self": "/Checkpoint/Server/1020"
          }
        },
        {
          "Id": 51926636515,
          "Type": "TransactionCheck",
          "Links": {
            "Self": "/MonitorCheck/51926636515/Transaction"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Links": {
    "Next": "/google.com",
    "Self": ""
  },
  "Cursors": {
    "Next": "",
    "Self": ""
  }
}";

                dynamic data = JObject.Parse(step2_resu);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(data.Id));


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data you want like this:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);

var timestamps = jo.SelectToken("Data")
    .Children<JObject>()
    .Select(o => new
    {
        Id = (string)o.SelectToken("Id"),
        Timestamp = (DateTime)o.SelectToken("Attributes.Timestamp")
    })
    .ToList();

foreach (var item in timestamps)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Id: " + item.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("TS: " + item.Timestamp);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

var next = (string)jo.SelectToken("Links.Next");
Console.WriteLine("Next: " + next);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cujviw

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.